# Submit Form using AJAX and jump to specific page depending on data in the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with a search box inside of it. Depending on what the user searches I jump to a specific page. Using $.ajax how can I jump to that url and send the data accordingly to that url?

HTML:

```
<form method = "POST">
<input id = "search"...>
</form>
```

JS

```
//When user presses enter submit the form, jump to the url


$("#search").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        form.submit();
    }

            var landingUrl = '/page/subpage/'; //page changes depending on what the user searched for so I can't put <form action = "/page/subpage/">
            var data = '...';

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                  data
              },
              url: (landingUrl),
              contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              success: function() {
                  console.log("post data sent");
              },
              error: function() {
                  $window.open(landingUrl, "_self");
              }
          });
         form.submit();
    });
```

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: use window.location instance of open

Comment: @Vijay where would I use this?

Comment: I think you should revise your question. What I think you are asking is: "How do I show the search results without page refresh with AJAX?"

Comment: @user3275665 I think I am overcomplicating it. I just want to send a POST request and jump to a specific url. When I get to that page I want to get that POST data